# How to test selector function with redux-saga-test-plan

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I am testing my redux-saga-flow, and I have an issue with testing selector method with select.

Selector

```
const selector = (state) => {
   console.log("selector");
   return data;
}
```

Redux saga flow

```
export function* testedSagaFlow() {
  const data = yield select(selector);
  if (!data) {
    return;
  }
  yield put (otherAction)
  ...
}
```

Test for flow

```
test("Get data from store", () => {
  return expectSaga(testedSagaFlow)
  .provide([[mathchers.select.selector(selector), null]])
  .select(selector)
  .not.put(otherAction)
  .run()
})
```

After running a test, a do not have `console.log("selector");` and also this line of code did not covered by test.

How can I test a selectors?

The same does not work with unit test.

```
test("Unit test flow", () => {
   const saga = testSaga(testedSagaFlow);
   saga
    .next()
    .select(selector)
    .next(null)
    .isDone()
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.1"`.

Option 1. Use [withState](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/state.html):

> For static state, you can just use the `withState` method to allow `select` effects to work.

Option 2. Use [static provider](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/mocking/static-providers.html)

> You can provide mock values in a terse manner via static providers. Pass in an array of tuple pairs (array pairs) into the `provide` method. For each pair, the first element should be a matcher for matching the effect and the second effect should be the mock value you want to provide.

E.g.

`saga.ts`:

```
import { put, select } from 'redux-saga/effects';

const otherAction = { type: 'OTHER_ACTION' };

export const selector = (state) => {
  console.log('selector');
  return state.data;
};

export function* testedSagaFlow() {
  const data = yield select(selector);
  if (!data) {
    return;
  }
  yield put(otherAction);
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { expectSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import { select } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { selector, testedSagaFlow } from './saga';

describe('70199170', () => {
  test('should dispatch other action', () => {
    const state = { data: true };
    return expectSaga(testedSagaFlow).withState(state).put({ type: 'OTHER_ACTION' }).run();
  });

  test('should return if data is nil', () => {
    const state = { data: null };
    return expectSaga(testedSagaFlow).withState(state).not.put({ type: 'OTHER_ACTION' }).run();
  });
});

describe('70199170 - use provider', () => {
  test('should dispatch other action', () => {
    return expectSaga(testedSagaFlow)
      .provide([[select(selector), true]])
      .put({ type: 'OTHER_ACTION' })
      .run();
  });

  test('should return if data is nil', () => {
    return expectSaga(testedSagaFlow)
      .provide([[select(selector), null]])
      .not.put({ type: 'OTHER_ACTION' })
      .run();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/70199170/saga.test.ts
  70199170
    ✓ should dispatch other action (30 ms)
    ✓ should return if data is nil (4 ms)
  70199170 - use provider
    ✓ should dispatch other action (2 ms)
    ✓ should return if data is nil (3 ms)

  console.log
    selector

      at selector (packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/70199170/saga.ts:6:11)

  console.log
    selector

      at selector (packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/70199170/saga.ts:6:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.934 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution a little bit later. And what you can suggest for unit tests with ```testSaga()?```

Comment: It is only one way to solve this problem? I mean, in my example, I used the provider and mock data as a second param in tuple.

Comment: @ElliZorro Updated answer, add test suites using [static provider](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/mocking/static-providers.html)

Comment: I use ```"redux-saga-test-plan": "4.0.3"``` and only first solution works for me :(